# A sample enterprise standard Spring application with tutotrial

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Can someone please help me find out an enterprise standard spring application with explanation tutorial

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html - however quite outdated

Comment: I know that. I want a more sophisticated one...Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clarify what your experience level is with design patterns and web development. Typically, Java EE developers use Spring and already have prior knowledge of design patterns. If you don't understand design patterns, it may make learning Spring much more difficult, and in which case you should start by learning design patterns.

If you need quick tutorials with Spring examples, I'd suggest [mkyoung's](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/) site. If you need a short introduction with a book, I'd suggest [Just Spring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449306403), which is only 50+ pages and easy to get through. For a more extensive Spring-MVC/Hibernate book, I found [Spring Persistence with Hibernate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226323) really helpful, because you can download source code of an entire Spring webapp from their website and get hands-on experience with the code. Even if you don't buy the book, I suggest you download the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Here are videos that make you write spring apps step by step...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GB8k2-Egfv0&feature=relmfu